# PNPM + Storybook "No Configuration files have been found in your configDir"

Tags: reactjs, vite, storybook, pnpm

I have a PNPM monorepo and I am trying to create a storybook documentation project or add it to a currently existing app with no success. The error I am getting is the same in both installation attempts:

`Error: No configuration files have been found in your configDir, Storybook needs "main.js" file, please add it (or pass a custom config dir flag to Storybook to tell where your main.js file is located at).`

I am using typescript so I can clearly see that main.ts exists but even if I rename to .js it has the same error:

**main.ts**

```
import type { StorybookConfig } from '@storybook/react-vite'

import { join, dirname } from 'path'

/**
 * This function is used to resolve the absolute path of a package.
 * It is needed in projects that use Yarn PnP or are set up within a monorepo.
 */
function getAbsolutePath(value: string): any {
    return dirname(require.resolve(join(value, 'package.json')))
}
const config: StorybookConfig = {
    stories: ['../src/**/*.mdx', '../src/**/*.stories.@(js|jsx|mjs|ts|tsx)'],
    addons: [
        getAbsolutePath('@storybook/addon-links'),
        getAbsolutePath('@storybook/addon-essentials'),
        getAbsolutePath('@storybook/addon-onboarding'),
        getAbsolutePath('@storybook/addon-interactions'),
    ],
    framework: {
        name: getAbsolutePath('@storybook/react-vite'),
        options: {},
    },
    docs: {
        autodocs: 'tag',
    },
}
export default config
```

**Steps to Install**

1. Add to existing vite-react app

I am installing using `pnpx storybook@latest init` I can see the .storybook folder with main.ts

2. Create storybook from empty folder

`pnpx storybook init --builder=vite` I can see this creates .storybook with a main.js inside however the error is the same

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you already found a solution, but it worked for me adding the following script in the package.json to run it locally:

```
"scripts": {
 "storybook:dev": "start-storybook dev --config-dir apps/storybook/.storybook -p 6006"
},
```

In this case my `.storybook` is not in the root folder, but in `apps/storybook/.storybook` as showed above.